Phrasing the difference between hanging and is hung
In English we can say both,

The pictures are hanging on the wall.

and

The pictures are hung on the wall.

The first might be in response to the question, "Where did you hang the pictures?" And the second might be in response to the direction, "You need to hang the pictures on the wall." In the first case the answer is saying where the pictures are positioned currently. In the second case the reply is saying that the task of hanging the pictures has already been completed in the past.
How are these distinctions phrased in Italian?
My question originated when looking at these Italian sentences and trying to understand 1) if they were correct Italian or not, and 2) if they said what I thought they did.

L'orologio è appeso alla parete.

which looks to me as if it says, "The clock is hung on the wall," and

L'orologio appende alla parete.

Which looks to me as if it says, "The clock hangs on the wall." From this I ventured that to say, "The clock is hanging on the wall," one might say in Italian

L'orologio sta appendendo alla parete.

and these sentences would contain the same distinctions that the English does. Is that correct?

Sorry, can you clarify better the difference in English? Is the first situation something more recent than the second one?

@DaG: Please see my edits. It is a distinction between a current state in the present and a state existing in the past. "Le foto sono appese alla parete," would seem to be only the second. How does one phrase the first in distinction?

So the second one would be something like “Le foto sono state appese alla parete”? But that would perhaps translate “The pictures have been hung on the wall.” Moreover, if the task has been completed in the past, then that is their current position. Perhaps it's a distinction that Italian doesn't have, or it's simply me. I'm still not sure I understand...

I will edit the post to try to clarify.

I'm not sure of the different nuances in English (and the Italian examples don't help too much, since some of them are incorrect), but here are some ways to describe pictures on the wall:

I quadri sono appesi al muro: They are there, with no information on when this happened or anything else.
I quadri sono stati appesi al muro: Someone, possibly in a recent past, has hung them.
Qualcuno ha appeso i quadri al muro or Hanno appeso i quadri al muro: Again, someone has hung them, with a nuance of explicitly omitting who.
I quadri vengono appesi al muro: A passive present form to say that they are being hung right now or to describe some kind of procedure (here, we don't store them in a chest, we hang them).

Notice that the Italian verb appendere is transitive, i.e., the subject has  to be the person that hangs something and the object is the thing (or person, in the case of a hanging) being hung. So you can't say *I quadri appendono alla parete or anything similar.
There is a cognate verb pendere which is intransitive instead, so in this case the subject is the thing fixed only by one or few points, but you would say it, more than of a picture, of something more precarious, oscillating, like a chandelier or something (il lampadario pende dal soffitto) or, with a different meaning, of something that leans. The leaning tower of Pisa is, in Italian, the torre pendente.

This is helpful because it points out that investigating the difference between English and Italian regarding the gerundio tense may answer my questions. But I do not believe you are correct about being able to use transitive verbs in the way you indicate above. Here is a example of such usage found in http://www.corpusitaliano.it: "Gli orecchi , insieme su piuttosto più superiore al livello degli occhi , stanno appendendo , del formato medio , la forma di v e circa la metà di lunghezza capa ." Isn't this correct Italian?
"

This is not Italian, it is a load of nonsense and lexical absurdities. The correct use of transitive and intransitive verbs is that described in the  answer.

@Michael: Unfortunately, the text you have found seems to be randomly generated, or mechanically (awfully) translated, or something like that.

@Michael : Of course you don't have to trust me: just check on an actual dictionary,such as https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/appendere/

I have learned not to trust Corpus Italiano for proper Italian. Thanks. Can anyone recommend a trustworthy source for corpus of proper Italian?

Look at this list of the library of the Scuola Normale Superiore https://biblio.sns.it/it/corpora-della-lingua-italiana#italianoantico

The pictures are hanging on the wall (focus on the status) becomes

I quadri sono appesi al muro

while The pictures are hung on the wall (focus on the act of hanging them already being completed) becomes

I quadri sono stati appesi al muro

which is the passive form of

(qualcuno) ha appeso i quadri al muro

